# Jquery if class appear after click

Tags: jquery

I have a list of div elements, when I click on this div, class "selected" appear. How I can check is this class appear and what exact div is selected.

```
<div class="swatch-attribute-options">
<div class="swatch-option color">
<div class="swatch-option color">
<div class="swatch-option color">
<div class="swatch-option color">
</div>
```

Click on some of div, adds class selected

So, how can I check if this class added, and determine exact div.

Thanks.

Comment: share you code also

Comment: $('div').click(function(){
       if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
           alert('Yes');
       } 
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to understand what do you need and i create a simple demo for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // when click the box class
  $('.box').click(function() {
    // check has selected class ?
    check = $(this).hasClass('selected');
    if (check) {
      // remove selected class
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
      // add and log selected class
      console.log('div ' + $(this).html() + ' Selected !')
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid silver;
}

.selected {
border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">One</div> <br/>
<div class="box">Two</div> <br/>
<div class="box">Three</div> <br/>
<div class="box">Four</div> <br/>
<div class="box">Five</div> <br/>
```

Comment: Changed the `alert` to `console.log` which is a bit more UI friendly, also `toggleClass` could shorten that code a lot

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what the desired outcome is, but if you are wanting to add or remove the class based on if the class has already been applied, you could use jQuery toggleclass.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
$('.swatch-option').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```